# which exception to throw while creating a bank application (2 use cases) in Spring Rest?

Tags: spring, rest, exception

I am currently working on some bank application where admin can create account for user .

so if user account exists already it should throw an exception so in that case  which one is valid to use ? Here Preconditions belong to guava library

```
 Preconditions.checkRequestState(user.getAccount == null) . if condition fails => throws IllegalStateException() //500
  or
ServicePreconditions.checkRequestState(user.getAccount == null) if condition fails => throws MyConflictException()  // 409
(custom exception i have created in rest-with-spring)
```

2nd use case => . if i want to withdaraw money from my account and balance is not sufficient . in that case which exception should be suitable that i have mentioned above .

```
 Preconditions.checkRequestState(withdrawAmount <= totalAmount)  if condition fails  => throws IllegalStateException() //500
    or
 ServicePreconditions.checkRequestState(withdrawAmount <= totalAmount) if condition fails => throws MyConflictException()  // 409 



public final class ServicePreconditions {
 public static void checkRequestState(final boolean expression) {
        if (!expression) {
            throw new MyConflictException();
        }
    }

}

// 409

@ExceptionHandler({InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException.class, DataAccessException.class, MyConflictException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request) {
    final ApiError apiError = message(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, ex);
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, apiError, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
}
```

Comment: It's up to you to create the exception you want. Eg. `AccountAlreadyExistsException` etc... I suggest you to handle each exception with a different handler

Comment: i understand this but what should be the status code and also why not illegalstateexception ?

Comment: 400 Bad Request. This is a validation error, which normally results in a 400, meaning "client error". This is for the first use case. An please limit your posts to _one_ question. These are the rules of SO

Comment: which exception and status code should be thrown for second use case ?